# Spinner not appearing in Full width under Text view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I need to display the Spinner below this TextView "Type of Mill".

Now the Spinner appears to the right of the Textview(Image 1) but i need it to appear below the textview in Full width of the device(Image 2).

1. [image]
2. [image]

Edit: Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the textview and your spinner inside LinearLayout vertical so that it'll appear as you want.
Something like this,

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:text="Type of Mill" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Glad it solved your problem. You can accept or upvote the answer if you like it :)